# My Ui will create Business Objects in every use? or not?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, layer

Trying to build a basic 3-layer architecture in my new application suite. For first time i want to start applying best design practices (like IoC/DI e.t.c).

My UI layer will have to create a BLL object in order to do its work.

Lets say that my UI needs to call BLL 10 times . Will i have to create my BLL object 10 times or i will have to create it once on form load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > My UI layer will have to create a BLL object in order to do its work.

Preferred practice is when interfaces of business layer objects are injected to your GUI form, on creation or later thru properties. In this case your form knows nothing about business layer objects, doesn't bother with instantiating them, and does only what it should - GUI interactions.

Personally I prefer constructor injection:

```
public class MyForm
{
    private IDocumentStorage documentStorage;
    private IJobsRegistrator jobsRegistrator;

    public MyForm(IDocumentStorage documentStorage, IJobsRegistrator jobsRegistrator)
    {
        this.documentStorage = documentStorage;
        this.jobsRegistrator = jobsRegistrator;
    }
}
```

Where `IDocumentStorage` and `IJobsRegistrator` are your business layer interfaces. You can use properties setters instead, if there are some limitations (say, you can have only parameterless constructor).

Comment: So if i understand correctly i will inject the BLL object in my UI many times at the moment of use.

Comment: @e4rthdog No, you inject them once on form creation and keep references.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to recreate your business objects with each call.
This helps maintain a stateless application, which is what you want if you're making an HTTP based website.

If this becomes a problem due to some really heavyweight objects, there are measures you can take, like creating object caches/pools, or saving things in the Session object. Don't go there unless you find you have to.

Comment: So for example if i have a simple barcode application that wants to check if a lot exists, every time the user presses the button i should create a BLL object (via injecting the DAL object to its constructor) and call the BLL method for lot check that will apply the logic i want and interact ith the DAL. Correct?

Comment: @e4rthdog My first thought is that something like this could be handled inside a static class/method. In which case you wouldnt need to instantiate anything. Is there some reason you need an actual object here?

Comment: I may need to have multiple dal depending on my backend db, and generally its gonna grow ovcer time in complication and needs

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... If you expect a straight answer to this you are in for a disappointment. The answer is - it depends.

If your object is a stateless lightweight object - go ahead create it every time if it makes your life easier.

On the other hand, if your object has to maintain state, or takes a lot of resources to create it has to be created as a singleton, with all the overhead necessary to create/manage singletons.

Both scenarios are supported by DI containers, but it is up to you to choose the right one for your scenario

Comment: If my BLL and DAL is used heavily by both windows forms and web apps , isn't singleton a bad choice?

Comment: It depends how you define "singleton" - most IoC containers support the notion of a singleton-type lifetime management, but that doesn't mean the object itself is implemented as a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

If the object is a service type class, that is, taking some input and providing some output (such as a repository type object), you'd want your UI layer to take a dependency on an abstract version of it, for example:

```
public class UILayerComponent
{
    private readonly IBLLObject _bllobject;

    public UILayerComponent(IBLLObject obj)
    {
        _bllobject = obj;
    }

}
```

but the UI layer should know nothing about the instantiation, the lifetime management of, or even the concrete implementation of, this object. This should be a job for your IoC container to deal with.

However, if the object is state-driven - for example, created by one user action, and updated or removed by another - then you should be creating and disposing of it when it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking - Simple 3 Tier

Tier 1 - Database
No logic here, just data retreival and storage via RDBMS mechanisms

Tier 2 - Business Logic/Data Access
Data Access objects (pass/get data to/from Tier 1, business objects should be created here) and Business Data (domain) objects should be created/populated/saved from here

Tier 2 User Interface
Does nothing but present data (in business objects obtained from Tier 2) to the user for user creation/manipulation